# C# PictureBox.SizeMode = Zoom does not redraw when assigning new images

Tags: c#, picturebox, onvif

I am working on a CCTV project which employs ONVIF. I use a Winform sample, which is provided by "ONVIF Device Manager" project, to obtain video frames from a camera. (You can find it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/files/%21sample_winform/))
It was working fine if I connect to one camera. But, if I connect to six cameras some picture box does not redraw when I assign new images in DrawFrame(). Two back rectangles contain a red ellipse in the attached picture are supposed to display an image. This issues only occur when picture box size mode is Zoom. As what I have tried, those picture boxes can only redraw if I call Application.DoEvent() or call PictureBox.Update()/Refresh() every time when I set a new image.

[Two red ellipses in the attached picture are supposed to display an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHHe2.png)

```
private void DrawFrame(VideoBuffer videoBuffer, PlaybackStatistics statistics)
{
    Bitmap bmp = img as Bitmap;
    BitmapData bd = null;
    try
    {
        bd = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);//bgra32

        using (var md = videoBuffer.Lock())
        {

            CopyMemory(bd.Scan0, md.value.scan0Ptr, videoBuff.stride * videoBuff.height);

            //bitmap.WritePixels(
            //    new Int32Rect(0, 0, videoBuffer.width, videoBuffer.height),
            //    md.value.scan0Ptr, videoBuffer.size, videoBuffer.stride,
            //    0, 0
            //);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        //errBox.Text = err.Message;
        Debug.Print("DrawFrame:: " + err.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        bmp.UnlockBits(bd);
    }
    imageBox.Image = bmp;
    /*Application.DoEvent() // not recommended since this method causes the current thread to be suspended
    or call imageBox.Update() // causes hanging on UI thread
    or imageBox.Refresh() // causes hanging on UI thread
    or PictureBox.Invalidate(), do nothing.*/
}
```

I create picture boxes and add to a panel following this code.

```
PictureBox ptBox = new PictureBox();
ptBox.Size = new Size(elementWidth, elementHeight);
ptBox.Name = "PictureBox_" + (j) + (i);
ptBox.Location = new Point(j * elementWidth, i * elementHeight); //relative location
ptBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
ptBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
mPanel.Controls.Add(ptBox);
```

After a week, I found that PictureBoxs occurs the error does not trigger **OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)** event. It leads to the error that new images are not redrawn.

Comment: Maybe `PictureBox.Invalidate()` would work as well.

Comment: AFAIK picturebox only draw red X for error image, so the graphic is from the source data.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I have tried `PictureBox.Invalidate()`, it did nothing.

Comment: "Causes hanging" is not encouraging of course.  Easy to get the UI thread to burn 100% core by slamming it with expensive code like this.  It then stops taking care of normal duties, like painting.  If you do this in a worker thread, check the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window since it probably already does, then assigning the Image property is not valid and likely to cause deadlock.  Notable is that the CopyMemory() call is wrong, it doesn't copy enough since every pixel takes 4 bytes in 32bppArgb.  So good code is 4 times worse, ouch.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes it is, what is your suggested solution?

Comment: Just the obvious stuff when "ouch" doesn't get the point home and you can't provide more details.  Spend more money on your hardware.  Lower the camera resolution. Use a control that was made to display video.  Try all of them.

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant, this question associated with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044684/c-sharp-bitmap-lockbits-unlockbits-in-multi-thread). There have two problems in the code. First, CopyMemory() slows down the UI thread. Second, the code uses Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to update UI. All the update UI requests will be put in a queue which would lead to delaying on UI update.